# How to write to a text file ignoring NA?

Tags: r

```
mat=matrix(1:6,ncol=2)
mat[1,1]=NA
mat[2,2]=NA
v1=as.vector(mat)
v1
[1] NA NA  3  4 NA  6
mat2=matrix(1:6,ncol=2)
mat2[3,1]=NA
v2=as.vector(mat2)
v2
[1]  1  2 NA  4  5  6
```

I want to write v1 and v2 as two columns named `id (from v1) and val (from v2)`to a text file.

i can use `write.table(...)` but with condition that do not writ out NA from v1. So start from v1 if it is value then write and also write corresponding value from v2. If NA, just ignore and go to next in v1.

desired output:

```
 id   val
 3    NA
 4    4
 6    6
```

Answer (score 1):

We can create the logical index with `is.na`, negate it `!` and use that to subset the rows in the 'data.frame' created with 'v1' and 'v2'.

```
d1 <- data.frame(id=v1,val=v2)[!is.na(v1),]
d2 <- d1[order(d1$id),]
d2 
#  id val
#3  3  NA
#4  4   4
#6  6   6

write.table(d2, 'yourfile.txt', row.names=FALSE, quote=FALSE)
```

Comment: Thanks.Is it possible to sort `id` from min to max before writing out? I know we use `sort` but I need `val` to follow?.

Comment: @temor We can use `order`.  Updated the post